# Comparar datos compartidos en dos columnas en Python

Tags: python

Comparé columnas en python, quería saber que datos de la columna 1 *(col1)* estaba en la columna 2 `(col2)`.

Utilicé lo siguiente:

```
set(df['col1']).intersection(set(df['col2']))
```

Me arrojo el resultado como:

```
set([u'TSC22D4', u'HSPB1', u'RARRES2', u'GNG11', u'PTPRZ1', u'MCM7', u'MEST', u'PON2', u'PTN', u'RHEB', u'PEG10', u'GRM3'])
```

¿La `u` es por intersección? Son datos muy grandes que no puedo saberlo sino usando estas herramientas.

Comment: lo que esta entre comillas como 'TSC22D4' son nombres de genes. Me refiero a la sintaxis, o no se como llamarle. El formato en que lo imprimio en la consola es normal? soy principiante.  Habria una forma de EDITAR esta lista ? quitar  las u y comillas para obtener una lista sin este formato?

Answer (score 1):

La `u` indica que se trata de una cadena *unicode*, que es una forma de codificar cadenas que admite letras de cualquier alfabeto, por contraposición al ascii que sólo admite las del alfabeto inglés.

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que estás imprimiendo directamente una variable de tipo "conjunto", que es el resultado de la operación. Python es muy flexible a la hora de permitirte mostrar cualquier variable por pantalla, pues siempre intenta convertir estas variables a un formato que se pueda ver y entender en la salida. En este caso lo que hace es mostrar la misma sintaxis con la que tú podrías re-crear el conjunto resultado a partir de una lista. Es decir, muestra `set()` y dentro de los paréntesis y entre corchetes, todos los elementos del conjunto separados por comas. Ya que cada elemento en este caso es una cadena Unicode, te la muestra con la sintaxis en que tendrías que escribirla en un programa python, es decir `u'contenido'`.

Si simplemente quieres el contenido, sin comillas, sin `u` y sin comas, no debes tratar de mostrar directamente el conjunto, sino iterar sobre él y mostrar tú mismo cada elemento de uno en uno. Por ejemplo:

```
resultado = set(df['col1']).intersection(set(df['col2']))
for elemento in resultado:
    print(elemento)
```

En este caso, cada `elemento` que la pasas a `print()` es una cadena Unicode, pero `print()` sabe mostrar estas cadenas sin recurrir a su "representación python" como hizo en el caso del conjunto. Las verás "normal", sin comillas ni `u`.

También puedes usar `join()` para convertir el conjunto resultado en una cadena que tenga separados por comas (o por el separador que prefieras) los elementos. Así:

```
cadena = ", ".join(resultado)
```

En tu caso la `cadena` contendría al final:

```
'MCM7, GNG11, PON2, RARRES2, HSPB1, GRM3, PTPRZ1, RHEB, PTN, MEST, PEG10, TSC22D4'
```